# How do we check whether a os.system() function has executed properly if not then print "os.system could not work"

Tags: python, os.system

How do we check whether an `os.system()` function has executed properly, and if it didn't then print `os.system could not work`?

For example:

```
import os
os.system('ping 192.168.1.1')
```

How do we know the cmd command was executed, and how can we get its return value?

Comment: `os.system` returns a exit status, `print help(os.system)`.

Comment: `os.system` passes on the return code, which is generally the indicator of these things.  But you should use `subprocess` instead, unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UNIX systems, the return value of `os.system()` is the status code returned by the command executed.

For Windows systems, it is little bit different and given by a specific enviroment variable, `COMSPEC`.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) for more details.